# Get Gtk Label Width size

Tags: c, gtk

Is it possible to get a label size?

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

GtkWidget *mainWindow, *titleLabel, *fixedFrame;

mainWindow = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);

//set window default size, and request size and all stuff

fixedFrame = gtk_fixed_new();
gtk_widget_set_size_request...
gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(mainWindow), fixedFrame);

titleLabel = gtk_label_new("Welcome!");
gtk_widget_set_size_request(titleLabel, x, y);

gtk_fixed_put(GTK_FIXED(fixedFrame), titleLabel, x1, y2);
```

I want to know the size of label `"Welcome"`, (`x`, `y`), to calculate the right
position in the frame, (`x1`, `y1`) but I don't know how to do this. I already tried a search in
the GTK documents but I had no success.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yay! i found a way, here how to do this

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

GtkWidget *mainWindow, *titleLabel, *fixedFrame;
GtkRequisition req;

mainWindow = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);

//set window default size, and request size and all stuff

fixedFrame = gtk_fixed_new();
gtk_widget_set_size_request...
gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(mainWindow), fixedFrame);

titleLabel = gtk_label_new("Welcome!");
gtk_widget_size_request(titleLabel, &req);
gtk_widget_set_size_request(titleLabel, req.width, req.height);

gtk_fixed_put(GTK_FIXED(fixedFrame), titleLabel, x1, y2);
```